# create alignment in Biopython without input file

Tags: biopython

I have an alignment of protein sequences in a dictionary (id_prot as key and aligned sequence as value; could be another format), and I would like to use this alignment to build a NJ tree with Biopython

However, according to the documentation, the only way to load sequences to be used for phylogenetic analyses is from an input file. For instance:

> aln = AlignIO.read('Tests/TreeConstruction/msa.phy', 'phylip')

Does anyone know how to load sequences in the aln variable without reading an input file ?

Comment: Go back a step or two- how did your alignment get read into a dictionary in the first place?

Comment: @Chris: I created it using a custom python script.

Comment: Your custom script could output a standard alignment format, then you've solved your problem

Comment: as stated below, I have hundred of thousands of alignments ... I would like to keep everything within python with no output file. Otherwise I could also use a standard NJ program instead of Biopython.

Answer (score 1):

Create the required input in Phylip format from your dictionary and load it with `StringIO`. Note that the The sequence/protein ID can be up to 10 characters long. [IDs less than 10 characters must have spaces appended to them to reach the 10 character fixed width.](http://scikit-bio.org/docs/0.5.0/generated/skbio.io.format.phylip.html#alignment-section)

```py
from Bio.Phylo.TreeConstruction import DistanceCalculator, DistanceTreeConstructor
from Bio import AlignIO
from io import StringIO

dct = {'Alpha':   'AACGTGGCCACAT',
       'Beta':    'AAGGTCGCCACAC',
       'Gamma':   'CAGTTCGCCACAA',
       'Delta':   'GAGATTTCCGCCT',
       'Epsilon': 'GAGATCTCCGCCC'}


count = len(dct)
length = max(map(len, dct.values()))

msa = f" {count} {length}\n"
msa += '\n'.join(f"{prot_id:<10} {sequence}" for prot_id, sequence in dct.items())
print(msa)
print()

aln = AlignIO.read(StringIO(msa), 'phylip')
print(aln)
print()

calculator = DistanceCalculator('identity')
dm = calculator.get_distance(aln)
print(dm)
print()

constructor = DistanceTreeConstructor(calculator, 'nj')
tree = constructor.build_tree(aln)
print(tree)
```

Output:

```
 5 13
Alpha      AACGTGGCCACAT
Beta       AAGGTCGCCACAC
Gamma      CAGTTCGCCACAA
Delta      GAGATTTCCGCCT
Epsilon    GAGATCTCCGCCC

SingleLetterAlphabet() alignment with 5 rows and 13 columns
AACGTGGCCACAT Alpha
AAGGTCGCCACAC Beta
CAGTTCGCCACAA Gamma
GAGATTTCCGCCT Delta
GAGATCTCCGCCC Epsilon

Alpha   0
Beta    0.23076923076923073 0
Gamma   0.3846153846153846  0.23076923076923073 0
Delta   0.5384615384615384  0.5384615384615384  0.5384615384615384  0
Epsilon 0.6153846153846154  0.3846153846153846  0.46153846153846156 0.15384615384615385 0
    Alpha   Beta    Gamma   Delta   Epsilon

Tree(rooted=False)
    Clade(branch_length=0, name='Inner3')
        Clade(branch_length=0.18269230769230765, name='Alpha')
        Clade(branch_length=0.04807692307692307, name='Beta')
        Clade(branch_length=0.04807692307692307, name='Inner2')
            Clade(branch_length=0.27884615384615385, name='Inner1')
                Clade(branch_length=0.051282051282051266, name='Epsilon')
                Clade(branch_length=0.10256410256410259, name='Delta')
            Clade(branch_length=0.14423076923076922, name='Gamma')
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. However, since I want to do it for hundred of thousands of times, I would like to not use an input file (to avoid I/O limitations).